# SQL query counts returns the same number

Tags: sql, mariadb

The following query:

```sql
Select t1.name
       , t1.email
       , t1.activated 
       , count(t2.id) as 'reporter'
       , count(t3.id) as 'comments'
       , count(t4.id) as 'reported'
from users t1
     inner join tickets as t2 on t1.id = t2.reporter_id
     inner join comments as t3 on t1.id = t3.user_id
     inner join tickets as t4 on t1.id = t4.reported_id
group by name
```

The counts return all 3 the same number

Comment: probably because there are N records after the three join inside each group, and so the count counts the same thing? maaaaybe you are looking for count distinct

Comment: Show us some example data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see sample data, current results and expect results.

But I'm guessing it's because your group by clause doesn't include the t1.email and t1.activated columns.

```
Select t1.name
       , t1.email
       , t1.activated 
       , count(t2.id) as 'reporter'
       , count(t3.id) as 'comments'
       , count(t4.id) as 'reported'
from users t1
     inner join tickets as t2 on t1.id = t2.reporter_id
     inner join comments as t3 on t1.id = t3.user_id
     inner join tickets as t4 on t1.id = t4.reported_id
group by name
       , t1.email
       , t1.activated
```

Without sample data, it's hard to be sure, but I don't think your joins do what you want them to do. You will only get results for users who have are both "reported" and "reporter", and those tickets include at least 1 comment from the user who reported it.

Answer (score 0):

`count()` returns the number of rows with non-`NULL` values.  The `id`s are presumably NOT `NULL` so they return the same values.

The quick-and-dirty solution to your problem is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT`:

```
Select t1.name, t1.email, t1.activated,
       count(distinct t2.id) as reporter,
       count(distinct t3.id) as comments,
       count(distinct t4.id) as reported
. . .
```

Do not use single quotes for column aliases!  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Note that your query will never return `0` values for any of the counts.  Also, this is more expensive than necessary.  I am not providing a more efficient solution here, because the above answers your question.  If you have other issues with the query, then ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.